# Can I avoid multiple timers?

Tags: java, android

In my app I want to do some stuff corresponding to each specific user response. User responses occur continuously with minimum 130 milliseconds interval. I want to run some code after 3 seconds, 10 seconds and after 30 seconds for each specific response. I know I can use multiple timers or handlers for delay. But how to do that with minimum load on processor and memory.

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: I didn’t write the code. I’m trying to find a way to avoid multiple timers.

Comment: You are welcome. In case the answer works out, please don't forget about accepting at some point.

Comment: just use one `android.os.Handler`, thats all - no need for any queue, sorting, kicking timer etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to keep a sorted queue of "upcoming" events.

Each time your single timer wakes you up, you simply check if the time has come to process the top element in that queue. If so, do what needs to be done for that event and remove it from the queue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’ll try to do it.

Comment: exactly what I came here to propose. the concept is called Event List Processing and this is the most efficient approach to reduce the load on the device. Just to add, the only issue is that this approach would not support periodic events since you cannot add millions of them to the future event list in advance even you know when they should be processed.

Comment: That part could be easily solved by re-inserting such periodic events back into the queue instead of just removing it.

Comment: I found your solution useful. Though I didn’t write the code till now, I accepted your answer. Thanks for your help. I also thank to everyone who showed interest in solving the problem.